# How to import figma Material dsp.json theme into react native paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper, figma

When designing using the Material 3 Design Kit and Material Theme Builder from figma, you can export your custom material design system in the form of a dsp.json. How do I pass the information in this json to the React Native Paper provider's theme parameter? Do I need to copy it manually, or is there another way to import it?